# Why am i getting 3 bytes instead 1 byte after hexadecimal/string/byte conversion in java?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I have this program:

```
    String hexadecimal = "AF";
    byte decimal[] = new byte[hexadecimal.length()/2];

    int j = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < decimal.length; i++)
    {
        decimal[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hexadecimal.substring(j,j+2),16); //Maybe the problem is this statement
        j = j + 2;
    }

    String s = new String(decimal);
    System.out.println("TOTAL LEN: " + s.length());

    byte aux[] = s.getBytes();
    System.out.println("TOTAL LEN: " + aux.length);
```

The first total is "1" and the second one is "3", i thought i would will get "1" in the second total. Why is happen this? My intention is generate another hexadecimal string with the same value as the original string (AF), but i am having this issue.

Regards!

P.D. Sorry for my english, let me know if i explained myself well.

Comment: Using a debugger, look at aux (which comes from s - look there too) and see what's in there.

Comment: Unable to follow you. I get two times TOTAL LEN: 1

Comment: @Poldie. Using the debugger I see the variable "aux" has three element with values "-17", "-65" and "-67", but the problem is the same, I don't know from where this values are coming.

Comment: @Nico If your goal is to convert an hexadecimal string value into an ASCII character your could do it like `System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt("AF", 16));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what exactly you try to achieve. But find below what you are doing.

`Integer.parseInt(hexadecimal.substring(j, j + 2), 16)` returns 175
`(byte) 175` is -81
`new String(decimal)` tries to create an `String` from this byte array related to your current character set (probably it's UTF-8)

As the byte array does not contain a valid representation of UTF-8 bytes the created `String` contains the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" for the Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD`. The UTF-8 byte representation for this codepoint is `EF BF BD` (or -17 -65 -67). That's why the second length is three.

Have a look here [Wikipedia UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). Any character with a codepoint <= `7F` can be represented by a single byte. For all other characters the first byte must have the bits 7 and 6 set `11......`. Which is not the case for the value `-81` which is `10101111`. There for this is not a valid codepoint and it's replaced with the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER".

Comment: Hello @SubOptimal, thanks for your answer. It's work know with Charset "US-ASCII".